# ClassLoad Failing. ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, jar, classloader, java-7, conflicting-libraries

I am trying to load a class from a JAR file. The class is called BasicLineFormatter. Since I am stating the class using a shell script using java -cp command. The class BasicLineFormatter exists in two of my jars, one bring the com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_8.5.0.jar and another is a third party jar. But i am trying to load it from one of the jars (the third party jar). So I added this code:

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("Path to JAR");
Enumeration<JarEntry> enumeration = jarFile.entries();

URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" + "Path to JAR" + "!/") };
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

System.out.println("Stating to load");
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    JarEntry je = enumeration.nextElement();
    if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
        continue;
    }
    String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
    if (className.contains("BasicLineFormatter")) {
        System.out.println("Class Name: " + className);
        className = className.replace('/', '.');
        Class c = cl.loadClass(className);
    }

}
```

But after that i still get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org/apache/http/message/BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:62)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
```

Can you please tell me what is going on here, or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: In your classpath, add the the third party jar before thinclient jar

Comment: @Optional Wow! thanks. It worked!!